# How to use unionWith with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch two independent documents in MongoDB and sort them via createdAt. MongoDB documentation mentions $unionWith but Mongoose doesn't have anything similar. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use aggregation

```
Model.aggregate([
{ $lookup: { from: "fromCollection", localField: "fieldName", foreignField: "fieldName", as: "joinedCollection" } }
])
```

Comment: $lookup works like a join right? That wouldn't work. As these are independent documents. No foreign field. 

I need to fetch them both are return them sorted via createdAt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can always use the aggregations methods from your Schema and insert valid MongoDB query.

It would look something like this:

```
const results = await MyModel.aggregate([
    {
      $unionWith: { /*rest of the query here*/ },
    }
  ];
);
```

Edit: As Dani suggested, $lookup can also work depending on what you want to perform, and it may actually be simpler in your use case.

Edit2: Looks like you want to have 2 different documents from different collections in an array, sorted by a field. That's not what $lookup do.

Why not getting the two documents, [lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) them before putting them in an array, and then [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them?

Comment: I was trying to do that. Can I make it work with Moogose exported Models?

$unionWith: { coll: OrderImportLog(), pipeline: [] } }
 
Instead of using the collection name?

Comment: I've updated my answer according to what I further understood.

Comment: That is a bad idea. What if we have a million records on each document.

Comment: So your first answer would do the trick! Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

> **It says unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unionWith.**

I'm using the mongoose package.

Here's the code

const model = require("~/models/pros");

```
query = await model.aggregate([
{
  $unionWith: {
    coll: "videoprospects",
  },
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    email: {
      $first: "$email",
    },
  },
},
{ $sort: { created_on: -1 } },
{ $skip: 20 },
{ $limit: 20 },
```

]);

Answer (score 0):

Okay to sum it up, it should be done through $unionWith only. Something like this would work.

```
const results = await MyModel.aggregate([
    {
      $unionWith: { coll: 'documentYouWantToUnionWith' }
    }
  ];
);
```

*Here is the link to the Mongo documentation for this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/*